# Data Structure and Algorithm

Tags: data-structures

Which of the following statements are correct (assuming O notation)?

1.Deleting an element is slower for a linked list than for an array

2.Random access of elements in an array is O(1)

3.Linked lists are more memory-efficient than arrays

Comment: 4. This site is not a place to dump your homework assignments. <-- that's the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

1. wrong, because: if you delete an array element at position i, you have to shift all elements after i one to the left. Thats O(n). In case of a Linked List, you can just "jump over" the deleted element by setting previous nodes .next reference to the node after the deleted node. this happens in O(1)
2. true, because: Arrays are accessed in that way that you know the base address of the Array and just add the offset (the index of the element you want to access). Thats just an addition and it's in O(1)
3. true because Linked List elements don't have to be subsequent, unlike Arrays. It doesn't matter where in the memory the single elements (Nodes) of the Linked List are, as long as the pointers are set correctly.